# Cannot display Macbook Pro on external projector

Tags: display, thunderbolt, projector

I've looked all over the internet but I've had no luck in finding out how to properly display my Macbook Pro on an external device. I've tried an Epson projector and a Sony TV and have had no success with either; I've plugged in other Macs into those devices and using the same cables and they work, so it is definitely on my Mac's end. Using a VGA adapter and Thunderbolt port. OSX 10.9.3. My Mac detects the external devices but nothing shows up on the actual displays. I've tried Mirroring options and still nothing. Any ideas would be really helpful (and sorry I know I'm not the most computer literate person).

2.5 GHz Intel Core processor, 4 GB Memory 1600 MHZ DDR3

Comment: Are you running gfxCardStatus?

Comment: I am currently not running gfxCardStatus. Should I?

Comment: Nope, it can just cause similar symptoms. If You're not using it, it can't be the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Following ensuring the hardware is working (you did that)

The process:

Plug in initiates the hand shake (who are you)

Results in showing the details in About this Mac, or Sys Preferences Display.

- check for correct display identified and what resolution was chosen.

Simultaneously Mac looked up in its database for what profile (plist) to use.

Simultaneously Mac selected a Display property (colors ect) profile.

- can be seen (or modified) in the Color Sync utility application in your utility folder.

Check all above, and verify the process/sequence in your Console.